Medium blog for your site
I’m getting very good results with my blog on Medium. I write 3-4 articles a week, share the links on social media, and use microtask platforms to boost views. This strategy has led to great results: tens of thousands of views and thousands of reads. Do you think it makes sense to link the company’s website to the Medium blog, or would it be better to have a standalone company blog on the official website?

It’s a brilliant idea to link your company’s website to your Medium blog. Since you’re already getting great results with Medium, this can drive traffic to your company’s site and enhance visibility. However, having a standalone company blog on your official website is also beneficial for long-term SEO and branding. You might consider doing both: continue leveraging Medium for exposure while building your company's blog for direct engagement and search engine benefits.
But content on Medium and your company's own blog should be different. Use Medium to attract traffic and increase visibility with engaging articles, while your company's blog on your official site should feature unique content directly related to your business and optimized for SEO. This approach helps reach different audiences and maximizes the effectiveness of your content strategy.

It all depends on your goals.
The idea itself is good, but having a blog on your website, especially if it can be used for SEO content, is also a great idea. The most optimal solution lies somewhere in the middle.
Here's a simple example: IBM has a blog on its website as well as several blogs on Medium. For instance, there are stories from IBM designers on Medium — https://medium.com/design-ibm.
One option could be to take a combined approach: for example, first publish an article on the company blog and then post a version of the article on Medium with a link back to the blog. This way, you can give the article some organic boost from a platform with a high rating.

Owning a blog on your own website gives you more freedom and control in the presentation and management of your content. You get to decide how everything is organized and can tailor your site to be as user-friendly and SEO-friendly as possible. That means the ability to optimize articles for specific keywords and use internal linking to give visibility a boost and control over how your brand is represented online.
In contrast to the other platforms, which sometimes change their rules of engagement or start fiddling with their algorithms, having a website of your own ensures that you have complete control-it creates a more permanent, more reliable resource for your business.
